# Will adding magnets increase the current from a treadmill DC- wind-powered generator?

Tags: low-power

Using average 8-10 mph speeds, my treadmill 6:1 pulley ratio, I'm getting 12-14 Volts output, but I'm disappointed in my anemic, 0.5 - 1.7 ampere, output. This results in barely more than a battery "trickle charge" maintenance status.

Will adding additional, radially arranged, permanent magnets to the outer steel case increase my power output?

Comment: Outer steel case? It's likely that will prevent the flux passing through the coils to any significant extent.

Comment: More power is easier to come by if you increase the propeller swept area.

Comment: Have you optimized your mechanical design? That is where you can find the most improvements. What is the size and type of your windmill?

Answer (score 2):

> *Will adding additional, radially arranged, permanent magnets to the
> outer steel case increase my power output?*

The basic thing about power is that you can get **no more** power out than what you put in mechanically. Then you have to consider power efficiency i.e. how much of the mechanical effort wasted on heat and friction and electrical losses.

So, adding more magnets is unlikely to boost efficiency very much but, it will probably increase the output voltage a volt or two because, the induced voltage is proportional to rate of change of magnetic flux and, if the peak flux increases then, so will the output voltage.

> *Will adding additional, radially arranged, permanent magnets to the
> outer steel case increase my power output?*

This may increase efficiency a tad and, you may get a higher current but, at the end of the day, you cannot get out more power than what you mechanically put in. And, what you propose may be totally ineffective because, the devil will be in the detail.

Comment: Adding magnets may or may not change the torque/speed curve. The maximum power transfer theorem tells us you get the most energy from a given electrical source if you match its impedance, and this works in mechanics too. So changing the torque/speed curve may improve power generation (or it may not)

Comment: @user253751 not sure if you are making a criticism of my answer or, offering an alternative answer. Please be clear or, maybe leave an alternative answer for the OP. Remember we are also talking about a wind powered generator.

Comment: I understand it is a wind-powered generator using a DC motor recycled from a treadmill. However, the same torque/speed curve thing does also apply to humans. A human cannot develop much power pushing on an aircraft carrier, nor pushing on a ping-pong ball - the optimal mechanical impedance is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Thank you, Andy aka. This answers my question.  I appreciate your reply and value your expertise.

Comment: ...and thank you: pjc 50, Mike, user253751, Mattman 944, and solar Mike.

Comment: @RichardM. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)